# Input 0 of layer conv2d_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [28, 28, 1]

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

Here's my convolution neural network

```
input_shape = (28,28.1)
class cnn_model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):

        super(cnn_model,self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape= input_shape)
        self.maxpool = layers.MaxPool2D((2,2))
        self.conv2 = layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation ='relu')
        self.conv3 = layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu')
        self.flatten = layers.Flatten()
        self.dense64 = layers.Dense(64,activation='relu')
        self.dense10 = layers.Dense(10,activation='relu')
    def call(self,inputs):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.dense64(x)
        x = self.dense10(x)
        return x
```

I am getting the following error

> model = cnn_model() print(model.call(train_data[0])) ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [28, 28, 1]

and the shape is `(28, 28, 1)`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your `input_shape` parameter looks fine, so I'm guessing `train_data[0]` doesn't have enough dimensions! Probably `train_data.shape` is something like `(N, H, W, C)`, which is ready to go into the model. However, `train_data[0].shape` will come out like `(H, W, C)` which has one less dimension than expected. If you want to feed a single sample to the model you would have to reshape `train_data[0]` to `(1, H, W, C)`, perhaps by using NumPy's [expand_dims](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).

Answer (score 0):

From your code snip,

```
input_shape = (28,28.1)
```

Is there any typo - `.` instead of `,` ? did you intend to write it as below ?

```
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
```